# Camiar la fecha con Jquery de un datatimeField generado con Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, datetime, django-forms

Tengo una vista que tiene un datetimepicker que genero con Django tal que así:

```
class una(forms.Form):
start_edited_date = forms.DateTimeField(label="Fecha inicio", widget=DateTimeWidget(usel10n=True, bootstrap_version=3), required=False)
end_edited_date = forms.DateTimeField(label="Fecha fin", widget=DateTimeWidget(usel10n=True, bootstrap_version=3),required=False)



helper = FormHelper()
helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
helper.layout = Layout(
    'start_edited_date',
    'end_edited_date'                        
)
```

y una función javascript en la página html donde se genera el formulario tal que así:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
          $('.glyphicon-pencil').on('click',function(){
              var dataURL = $(this).attr('data-href');
              var res = dataURL.split(",");
              $('#id_start_edited_date').val(res[0]);
              $('#id_end_edited_date').val({
                    date: new Date(res[1])
              });
              $('#edit_id').val(res[2]);

          });
```

Pues cuando pincho en el botón que abre el formulario, no tiene el datetimepicker la hora puesta y aparece vacío.

¿Alguna idea?

Gracias.

Comment: para usar el datetimepicker necesitas librerias y un script js para activar asi como tambien añadir la clase css al input. el codigo que has puesto no es  suficiente para poder ayudarte, tambien necesitaria saber si te sale algun mensaje de error por la consola del navegador.

Comment: Claro, si pongo todo el código son más de mil líneas, por lo que puse la parte importante para localizar el error. aun así ya lo solucioné. Gracias.

Comment: Hola. Si ya tienes la solución entonces responde tu mismo a tu pregunta y luego acepta tu propia respuesta. De lo contrario, la pregunta permanece abierta.

Comment: Lo haría, pero parece ser que la comunidad me ha bloqueado por considerar que mis respuestas no valen nada. Ya se ve el poco respeto que tienen. Así que nada, que se quede abierta, no voy a contribuir más a esta comunidad.